# Extra speaker for combo amp?

Tags: amplifiers, speakers

Is it okay to hook up an additional 112 speaker *directly* to my 110 speaker combo amp? Will it damage the amplifier by adding an additional speaker? It's not wired for another output, no external speaker, but I'd like to install one.

Comment: Having composed an answer,I feel this question would be better migrated to a more technical site.Yes, it's quite feasible, but care needs to be taken.

Comment: The answers to http://music.stackexchange.com/q/11073/104 may help you. I think the question itself is more suited to electronics Stack Exchange, but you'd need to give them much more information. It is relatively straightforward for an experienced electronics engineer, but if you haven't done it before, there is a high risk of destroying your amp.

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing the answers are No & Yes

Comment: What do you expect to gain by doing this?  Just more sound? (then get a proper input splitter and drive a separate amp) A different frequency response? (then get a preamp)

Comment: @davidstrachan The answers are always "No" and "Yes". Because if you know what you're doing, the questions aren't asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just literally wiring in an additional speaker in addition to (or even in place of) the existing speaker is likely to result in damage to the amp and/or speakers.  A key consideration in this is the idea of [impedance matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) -- the amplifier electronics, the power amp in particular, are designed to operate against an electrical load with specific characteristics (impedance).

There will need to be additional modifications to the amp, wiring or speakers necessary to add an additional speaker to a combo that is not already designed for it.